# Use Gmail iOS Token in PHP script

Tags: php, ios, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail

I have an iOS app that logs in at GMail and retrieves a token which a PHP should use to make different actions on that user's inbox, but there is a small issue here: you can't use that token unless you're making actions from an iOS device. You can make stuff from that PHP if you login and give your consent from the browser... I think you got the point.

Is there anyway to convert those access tokens somehow that you won't be forced to login from the browser? Thanks.

Comment: could you find an answer?

Comment: I can't remember since it's been a while, but I think you have to use the web app token and it will work. Try that and tell me if it worked.